# windows has recovered from unexpected shutdown 'blue screen'

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-error-reporting, bluescreenview

I tried to hibernate my dell laptop, it takes very long time then a blue screen appears. the computer restarts showing a dialog including this information.

I'm using windows 7 and it's fresh installed.

> Problem signature:
>
> > Problem Event Name:  BlueScreen
> > OS Version: 6.1.7600.2.0.0.256.1
> > Locale ID:  1033
> > Additional information about the problem:
> > BCCode: 1000009f
> > BCP1:   0000000000000004
> > BCP2:   0000000000000258
> > BCP3:   FFFFFA80039E4040
> > BCP4:   FFFFF80000B9C4D0
> > OS Version: 6_1_7600
> > Service Pack:   0_0
> > Product:    256_1
>
> Files that help describe the problem:
>
> > C:\Windows\Minidump\012417-26660-01.dmp
> > C:\Users\Ahmad Khattab\AppData\Local\Temp\WER-1845897-0.sysdata.xml

Comment: It’s a driver problem. Please provide the minidump file. You can’t upload files here, so you’ll have to use some other hosting service.

Comment: thanks, here is the file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8RwKqMtOQwmcjFYR1hhWDFuRGc/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both crash dumps hint at a driver called “CH9100NIC64”. It is a network adapter driver. Apparently, it belongs to some USB Ethernet adapter.

Assuming that you have a USB Ethernet adapter, remove it and ideally the driver, too. Try again.

Consider buying a different adapter. This one was probably cheap for a reason.